Unable to generate additionalProperties in openAPI specs from the @Schema annotation
Below is snippet of my openApi 3 spec file-
"MyRequest": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "address1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "address2": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },

I need additionalProperties populated either in a schema or as a seperate property like below -
"MyRequest": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "address1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "address2": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },

I tried to add @Schema annotation in MyRequest pojo in my spring boot application.
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Schema(additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.FALSE)
public class MyRequest {    
    private String address1;
    ....

But this is not generating the "additionalProperties" in my openApi file.
How to accomplish this please?
